# How can I use randomisation to specify different object parameters to a single iteration in a loop?

Tags: java, javafx

I currently have a simple for-loop with 5 iterations that creates 'brick' game objects, adds them into the 'bricks' array and laying them out across the x axis of my javaFX scene. currently, as you can see on the Gameobj parameters; they are all blue. However, I want to have one of these bricks set as yellow on a random iteration of the loop. Here is my code:

```
    public void initialiseGame()
    {       
        bricks = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            GameObj brick = new GameObj(i*100, 100, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT, Color.BLUE);
            brick.moveX(75);
            brick.visible = true;
            bricks.add(brick);
            System.out.println("Model:: Create Brick =" + brick);
        }
    }
```

Here is the game object method setup:

```
    public GameObj( int x, int y, int w, int h, Color c )
    {
        topX   = x;       
        topY = y;
        width  = w; 
        height = h; 
        colour = c;
    }
```

How exactly can I use some sort of randomiser to change the colour of the brick on a single iteration?

Comment: Generate a random integer between 0 and 4 and then compare the loop counter to that integer. If it matches use yellow, if it doesn't use blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a random number in the range `[0, 5)` before the loop, and then set the color to yellow if the loop index matches that number:

```
Random random = new Random();
int yellowBrick = random.nextInt(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Color color = i == yellowBrick ? Color.YELLOW : Color.BLUE;
    GameObj brick = new GameObj(i*100, 100, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT, color);
    brick.moveX(75);
    brick.visible = true;
    bricks.add(brick);
    System.out.println("Model:: Create Brick =" + brick);
}
```

Comment: Hey David, I have a follow-up question on a bit of code relating to this, but it's too long to post as this comment, where is best to ask it?

Comment: @Timbo The best thing to do would be to post it as a new question.

Comment: I have created the post here, but already been downvoted as I expected, your help would be appreciated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291055/how-do-i-target-my-random-colour-variable-in-my-if-statement/60291137#60291137

Comment: @Timbo I upvoted your question. I think the answer you got is a good one. Use a property of the GameObj to determine how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `GameObj brick = new GameObj(i*100, 100, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT, Color.BLUE);`.

For example:
You can call `int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 5)` outside the for-loop. And then use this inside the for-loop:

```
if (random != i) {
  GameObj brick = new GameObj(i*100, 100, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT, Color.BLUE);
} else {
  GameObj brick = new GameObj(i*100, 100, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT, Color.YELLOW);
}
```

For more information on `Color` visit [Java™ Platform
Standard Ed. 8 Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)

Or you can use the [Math.random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) function.

Comment: This answer seems to completely misunderstand the question.